# SPARQL-Query doesn't yield expected results

Tags: sparql, virtuoso

I have a Virtuoso Server and run a SPARQL-Query against it, which doesn't yield the expected results. I'm not quite sure what the problem might be, so I hope some of you have an idea where to look.

This is my [SPARQL-Endpoint](http://creativeartefact.org/sparql)

The query

```
select * 
where
  {  ?s  ?p  <http://creativeartefact.org/gemachecker/42249795-6466-4997-8739-06042f2a7b4b>  .  }
```

yields one result:

```
http://creativeartefact.org/gemachecker/a680ca40-5cfb-4c45-930c-b990ab21766f    http://creativeartefact.org/ontology/organisedBy
```

When I use the result for `?p` in the query like:

```
select * 
where
  {  ?s  <http://creativeartefact.org/ontology/organisedBy> <http://creativeartefact.org/gemachecker/42249795-6466-4997-8739-06042f2a7b4b>  . }
```

I don't get any result.

For other objects, it works perfectly, like:

```
select * 
where
  {  ?s  <http://creativeartefact.org/ontology/organisedBy>  <http://creativeartefact.org/example/fe8badaf-93c6-4460-82ab-78d29bc4ea72>  . }
```

I have no idea why it works for one URI but not for the other. Any help pointing me toward the answer is appreciated!

Comment: I note you're running Virtuoso Open Source 07.00.3203 (a/k/a v7.0).  That's long outdated.  Updating to 07.20.3214 (a/k/a v7.2.1) is strongly recommended, whether you build from `stable` or `develop` branch.  Some [detail of the updates can be seen here](http://virtuoso.openlinksw.com/dataspace/doc/dav/wiki/Main/VOSNews), and [more here](https://github.com/openlink/virtuoso-opensource/blob/stable/7/ChangeLog).

Answer (score 0):

Try deleting the triple and adding it again. Virtuoso stores its triples in an underlying relational database, and if there is something corrupted in the way that a triple was created, it may result in strange behaviour. It doesn't seem like there is a problem from a SPARQL pov.

Comment: I did delete and re-add the triple, but it still doesn't yield the result. Maybe there is more broken than just this triple? Maybe the request was cached? Well, I changed my code to use the first query and looping through the result set to get all the results with the specific predicate.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the query solution at: 
http://creativeartefact.org/sparql?default-graph-uri=http%3A%2F%2Fcreativeartefact.org%2F&query=%23+select+*+%0D%0A%23+where+%7B++%3Fs++%3Fp++%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fcreativeartefact.org%2Fgemachecker%2F42249795-6466-4997-8739-06042f2a7b4b%3E++.++%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aselect+*+%0D%0Awhere+%7B++%3Fs++%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fcreativeartefact.org%2Fontology%2ForganisedBy%3E+%3Fo+.+%7D&should-sponge=&format=text%2Fhtml&timeout=0&debug=on

And the query text at: http://creativeartefact.org/sparql?default-graph-uri=http%3A%2F%2Fcreativeartefact.org%2F&qtxt=%23+select+*+%0D%0A%23+where+%7B++%3Fs++%3Fp++%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fcreativeartefact.org%2Fgemachecker%2F42249795-6466-4997-8739-06042f2a7b4b%3E++.++%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aselect+*+%0D%0Awhere+%7B++%3Fs++%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fcreativeartefact.org%2Fontology%2ForganisedBy%3E+%3Fo+.+%7D&should-sponge=&format=text%2Fhtml&timeout=0&debug=on

There is something wrong with the data in the DBMS. As a first step, could you try a later version of the 7.x release that you are using. At the very least, this will aid problem isolation e.g., if this is a bug specific to an older release, for instance.